# When table hits 10 rows, assign unique ID to these rows

Tags: php, mysql, queue

How can I do this in procedural PHP.
• People that click a button on my website are put with their unique data (which is already done) into the table.
• When the table hits 10 rows/persons, assign an unique ID (needs to be same for them 10) to these 10 people (like a lobby id).
• Generate a page for people that have that unique ID.

I know this is complicated and too much to ask, if I could atleast get directions on what to do it would be appreciated.

EDIT: Since it's 04:36, i'll go to sleep now. Thank you all for your suggestions and help. Will try this tomorrow :) Good night!

Comment: Why do you need the 10 to have the same id? Can't you just pull 10 entries from the table?

Comment: First of all, I'm beginner in PHP & MySQL so I have no idea what you meant. I just need to generate a page for those 10 people. I was thinking of getting them all a same id and generating a page for that ID.

Comment: then perhaps you need to start with some basics, this is way to broad for a question on stack overflow

Comment: Its a shame your question is so broad and will end up being closed soon as I would have enjoyed the challenge of helping you. Here is a tip though - break it down into small steps of what needs to happen. Draw it out on paper even with boxes and arrows in a flow chart type arrangement. You then know all the component steps for what you need to create code for and your on your way. It also provides you with the basics that you can come back and ask specific questions to get help with.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you already have that unique ID. Look here:

```
Preson 01: Alan, ...
Preson 02: Bob, ...
Preson 03: Clarice, ...
...
Preson 09: James, ...

Preson 10: Samanta, ...
Preson 11: John, ...
Preson 12: Suzie, ...
...
Preson 19: Tony, ...

Preson 20: XXX, ...
Preson 21: XXX, ...
Preson 22: XXX, ...
...
Preson 29: XXX, ...
```

So, just `uniqueID = intval(personId / 10) + 1`'d it...

And when you register new person:

```
$person = $this->savePersonData($data);
$personId = $person->id;
$uniqueID = intval($personId / 10) + 1;

// redirect that person to his specific lobby url
header("Location: http://host.name/lobby/{$uniqueID}/visit");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, another and more standard way of doing that is telling mysql that you want 10 people starting at id #

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

So in your case you would use something like this for your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1";
```

Where OFFSET is the ($page - 1) * 10
Where $page is the page of people you want to get. So if you want to get the second page it would be (2 - 1) * 10 = 10

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10";
```

The `LIMIT 10` statement tells mysql to only return the next 10 entries.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have an `id` column defined in the database as `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.  That way when you insert each person's data into the table, `id` will be set to the next int.  To determine that person's lobby_id, just calculate `ID DIV 10` (divides and floors to lower int).

```
SELECT id, id DIV 10 AS lobby_id, other, columns
FROM my_table
WHERE ....
```